# nvd3.js and daterangepicker.js combiningly not working

Tags: charts, line, nvd3.js

I am using nvd3 for making a line chart. I include `date-picker/daterangepicker.js` also for selecting range of date. But my graph is not working. If I exclude the daterangepicker.js then graph is working properly. 
My Code is like:

```
var testdata = [
                {
                  "key" : "Price" ,
                  "values" : [ [ 1376611200000 , 71.89] , [ 1379289600000 , 75.51] , [ 1141102800000 , 68.49] , [ 1143781200000 , 62.72] , [ 1146369600000 , 70.39] , [ 1149048000000 , 59.77] , [ 1151640000000 , 57.27] , [ 1154318400000 , 67.96] , [ 1156996800000 , 67.85] , [ 1159588800000 , 76.98] , [ 1162270800000 , 81.08] , [ 1164862800000 , 91.66] , [ 1167541200000 , 84.84] , [ 1170219600000 , 85.73] , [ 1172638800000 , 84.61] , [ 1175313600000 , 92.91] , [ 1177905600000 , 99.8] , [ 1180584000000 , 121.191] , [ 1183176000000 , 122.04] , [ 1185854400000 , 131.76] , [ 1188532800000 , 138.48] , [ 1191124800000 , 153.47] , [ 1193803200000 , 189.95] , [ 1196398800000 , 182.22] , [ 1199077200000 , 198.08] , [ 1201755600000 , 135.36] , [ 1204261200000 , 125.02] , [ 1206936000000 , 143.5] , [ 1209528000000 , 173.95] , [ 1212206400000 , 188.75] , [ 1214798400000 , 167.44] , [ 1217476800000 , 158.95] , [ 1220155200000 , 169.53] , [ 1222747200000 , 113.66] , [ 1225425600000 , 107.59] , [ 1228021200000 , 92.67] , [ 1230699600000 , 85.35] , [ 1233378000000 , 90.13] , [ 1235797200000 , 89.31] , [ 1238472000000 , 105.12] , [ 1241064000000 , 125.83] , [ 1243742400000 , 135.81] , [ 1246334400000 , 142.43] , [ 1249012800000 , 163.39] , [ 1251691200000 , 168.21] , [ 1254283200000 , 185.35] , [ 1256961600000 , 188.5] , [ 1259557200000 , 199.91] , [ 1262235600000 , 210.732] , [ 1264914000000 , 192.063] , [ 1267333200000 , 204.62] , [ 1270008000000 , 235.0] , [ 1272600000000 , 261.09] , [ 1275278400000 , 256.88] , [ 1277870400000 , 251.53] , [ 1280548800000 , 257.25] , [ 1283227200000 , 243.1] , [ 1285819200000 , 283.75] , [ 1288497600000 , 300.98] , [ 1291093200000 , 311.15] , [ 1293771600000 , 322.56] , [ 1296450000000 , 339.32] , [ 1298869200000 , 353.21] , [ 1301544000000 , 348.5075] , [ 1304136000000 , 350.13] , [ 1306814400000 , 347.83] , [ 1309406400000 , 335.67] , [ 1312084800000 , 390.48] , [ 1314763200000 , 384.83] , [ 1317355200000 , 381.32] , [ 1320033600000 , 404.78] , [ 1322629200000 , 382.2] , [ 1325307600000 , 405.0] , [ 1327986000000 , 456.48] , [ 1330491600000 , 542.44] , [ 1333166400000 , 599.55] , [ 1335758400000 , 583.98] ]
                }
              ].map(function(series) {
                series.values = series.values.map(function(d) { return {x: d[0], y: d[1] } });
                return series;
              });

              var chart;
              nv.addGraph(function() {
                    chart = nv.models.linePlusBarChart()
                        .margin({top: 30, right: 60, bottom: 50, left: 70})
                        .x(function(d,i) { return i })
                        .color(d3.scale.category10().range());

                    chart.xAxis.tickFormat(function(d) {
                      var dx = testdata[0].values[d] && testdata[0].values[d].x || 0;
                      return dx ? d3.time.format('%x')(new Date(dx)) : '';
                      })
                      .showMaxMin(false);

                    chart.y1Axis
                        .tickFormat(d3.format(',f'));

                    chart.y2Axis
                        .tickFormat(function(d) { return '$' + d3.format(',.2f')(d) });

                    chart.bars.forceY([0]).padData(false);
                    //chart.lines.forceY([0]);

                    d3.select('#lineChart svg')
                        .datum(testdata)
                      .transition().duration(500).call(chart);

                    nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

                    //chart.dispatch.on('stateChange', function(e) { nv.log('New State:', JSON.stringify(e)); });

                    return chart;
                });
```

Is there any way to solve this issue?

Please guide me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry that i'm unable to comment.

I couldn't see any html scripts where you're loading the daterangepicker. Please provide more information.

And daterangepicker.js cannot be used alone. It relies on Bootstrap, jQuery and Moment.js. Here is the link that would help you. [**Date Range Picker**](https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker).

Answer (score 0):

Daterangepicker defines the function Date.now() which d3 also uses, however this function returns a string such as `Mon Apr 27 2015 19:01:54 GMT+0800` for daterangepicker while this function should return a integer like `1430129920761` for d3, so d3 will behave wrong. You could change the d3.js script and replace the function defination

```
    if (!Date.now) Date.now = function() {
        return +new Date();
    };
```

with another name such as Date.intNow() and then replace all the places which Date.now() is used by Date.intNow(), and then the problem will be resolved